# Xcode 7.2 XCode crashes when typing "func"

Tags: xcode, crash

Xcode crashes again :-(

When typing func in an editor it crashes. 
Any hints ? Where to find any logs ?

I already restarted the mac. I rebuilt the project.

Answer (score 0):

Give detail. Show images for example.